# Form submission results in a blank page in PHP

Tags: php, isset

I am trying to make a login system and i want to create a conditional statement that checks whether the global variable $_POST['submit-form'] is set.

If the global variable $_POST['submit-form'] is set then i want to echo out the fields of the submitted forms. This works fine..

The problem comes when i want to check whether the global variable $_POST['submit-form'] is empty, i get a blank page when i submit the form with nothing. It is supposed to echo out something like "You have entered nothing, please try again'.

I don't know what is wrong.

This is the code for the form.

```
  <form action="test-form2.php" method="POST">


      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>


    <input type="submit" name="submit-form" value="submit">


  </form>
```

..and this is the code for the form handler.

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {


        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];


      if(($_POST['name'] != "") && ($_POST['email']!= "")) {    

          echo "This is your name: ".$name."<br>";
           echo "This is your email: ".$email;

      // header('refresh=3;url = ../leden/index.php');

       }

    } else {

          echo "You have entered nothing or your username and/or password is incorrect, please try again.";

      // header('refresh=3;url = /test-form1.php');

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that checking if it's set isn't enough .. Because it may be set *and* be empty --  Realistically what you want is to check **both** `isset` and whether it's `empty`  IE:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-form'] && $_POST['submit-form'] != '' && $_POST['submit-form'] != null)
```

If the above `if` statement **fails** your *value* for `$_POST['submit-form']` is most likely not being submitted.

**UPDATE**
Check for blank fields

```
if ($_POST['name'] != '' && $_POST['email'] != ''){
   // Do stuff
}else{
    if ($_POST['name'] == ''){
       echo "name is empty";
    }
    if ($_POST['email'] == ''){
       echo "email is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining i will try and see if i can make it work.

Comment: Hi Zak, it is not working, the form is still being submitted albeit with empty fields. At least now i don't get a blank page, but it is not checking whether the form fields were empty when the form was submitted.

Comment: Yes this worked, i was checking the submit button every time.. this was the mistake. I have to check the specific form fields for values. Thank you, you rock!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `$_POST` always have `submit-form` (and it's always not empty), so `if` statement always returns `true`. Try to check (for example) only that `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']` are not empty.

Comment: Oh yes.. i see. Thank you i will try this now.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `isset($_POST['submit-form'])` returns `true` even if you don't input anything in *Name* and *E-mail* fields, it's value would be `submit` string when hit *submit* button to submit the form. This is the reason `else` part of below block is not getting executed.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {

} else {
      echo "You have entered nothing or your username and/or password is incorrect, please try again.";
}
```

Use `var_dump($_POST);` to see the complete array structure. having said these, you can use the following snippet to achieve the desired result,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if(($_POST['name'] != "") && ($_POST['email']!= "")) {    
        echo "This is your name: ".$name."<br>";
        echo "This is your email: ".$email;
        // header('refresh=3;url = ../leden/index.php');
   }else{
       echo "You have entered nothing or your username and/or password is incorrect, please try again.";
   }
}
```

Validation and scrutinization of user inputs should be your next action items in the list.

Comment: Yes you did it! it works now. So i have to check whether the form fields are set and not the submit button? i think i am beginning to understand now.Thank you so much @Rajdeep !

Comment: @JhonattanRapprecht Glad I could help! Happy coding! :-)